# Ember.js - Bind array to radio button in the table/grid and when user selects the one in grid/table update the same array

Tags: arrays, ember.js

> following is my code: when i click any row in grid /table i should be
>   able to update the array elements back in the array

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <table border="1">
      {{#each content}}
        <tr><td>{{name}} {{view Ember.RadioButton name="selectionTest" selectionBinding="isSelected" valueBinding="name"}}</td></tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
    <div>Is Selected: {{isSelected}}</div>
</script>


console.clear();
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});

Ember.RadioButton = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: "input",
    type: "radio",
    arrBinding: 'App.ApplicationController.content',
    attributeBindings: ["name", "type", "value", "checked:checked:"],
    click: function () {
        this.set("selection", this.$().val())
        alert(this.$().val());        
    alert(arrBinding);
    },
    checked: function () {
        return this.get("value") == this.get("selection");

    }.property()
});
```

> here i have declared the array elements

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
      isSelected: 'Ashish',

    content:[
        {
            name: 'Ashish',
            selected: false
        },
         {
            name: 'Eben',
            selected: false
        },
         {
            name: 'Ronald',
            selected: false
        },
         {
            name: 'Jamie',
            selected: false
        }
    ]
});
```

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CM6fK/169/

Comment: Did you have a question?  What's working, what's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure what you're asking, but for a start you need to bind you selectionBinding to your controller:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <table border="1">
      {{#each content}}
        <tr><td>{{name}} {{view Ember.RadioButton name="selectionTest" selectionBinding=this.controller.isSelected valueBinding="name"}}</td></tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
    <div>Is Selected: {{isSelected}}</div>
</script>
```

And as for the other bit. I think you need to change:

```
    alert(arrBinding);
```

to

```
    alert(this.arrBinding);
```

Though I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve there.

Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CM6fK/172/

Comment: I am looking for the array returned with the updated values. Like if i select the first element then i should get the array returned with the first value true and other false

Comment: I am looking for the array returned with the updated values. Like if i select the first element then i should get the array returned with the first value true and other false